# 7zip command line backup script acting weird

Tags: batch-file, backup, 7zip

I am creating a small backup script for my personal use, and it works at 99% on the latest version of 7zip, Win7x64 :

> :: u : Update archive
>
> :: -t7z : Use 7z file type (less compatible and smaller results)
>
> :: -mx=9 : "Ultra" compression
>
> :: -ms=off : Do not create solid archive (they are incompatible with update archive mode)
>
> :: -mmt=off : Enable multithreading
>
> :: -r : Recursive (traverse all subdirectories)
>
> :: -ssw : Compress locked files
>
> :: -w : Working dir to G: drive (no temp file copy from disk to disk)
>
> @echo "%userprofile%\Desktop"              >> list.txt
>
> @echo "%userprofile%\Documents"            >> list.txt
>
> @echo "%userprofile%\Downloads"            >> list.txt
>
> @echo "%userprofile%\Saved Games"          >> list.txt
>
> @echo "%userprofile%\Pictures"             >> list.txt
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -t7z -mx=9 -ms=off -mmt=on -r -ssw -wg: "G:\AutoSaveC\SaveC.7z" @list.txt
>
> del list.txt
>
> shutdown -s -t 180

There are two problems tho :

1- Even though the archive contains all expected folders and files, it also contains stuff never intended to be there (only part of the files from the original folders) :

> %userprofile%\AppData
>
> %userprofile%\Music

2- It also gives me warnings about denied access to folders I NEVER told it to look at :

> C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Application Data\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\ElevatedDiagnostics\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\History\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\msdtadmin\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Application Data\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Cookies\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Local Settings\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Recent\:  WARNING: Access denied.
>   C:\Users\LocalAdmin\SendTo\:  WARNING: Access denied.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ? Or is it a bug from 7zip ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that there may be soft links to files in those directories. The Users folder in particular is filled with virtual paths. There are paths in there that exist solely to redirect older applications that still use them to the proper location.

Comment: By "Soft links" do you mean *.lnk files ? Because if that's the case none of those files in the folders I'm trying to save are pointing to any locations outside of the scope of my backup... - Good intuition though...

Comment: I mean soft links as in files that show up as normal files but are actually located in other directories. Sometimes Microsoft applications create these links (and they might be hidden files). That's how you can have a Documents folder in the User's directory that actually points to a folder located somewhere else. This way, if you had a program or script that wanted to copy something to the Documents folder, it will go to the right place.

Comment: Oh noes - so do you have any idea on how I could rework the script to get around that ? My original script did not have any of the %userprofile% variables called, but only explicit paths - and it acted the same... What could I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much you CAN do without making your script really ugly to add exceptions (which I unfortunately couldn't tell you how to do). However, as is, the warnings are safe to ignore. If you really want to get rid of those extra folders, maybe you can delete them from the archive after everything else is added?

Comment: So there's no way for me to visualize these links and edit them ? Oh well. Quick and dirty will do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing the contents of the directory the way you are doing it, why not redirect the output of DIR to your text file instead? This way, you can filter out hidden files, .lnk files, system files, and many other options for file filtering are at your disposal. For instance, to weed out hidden, system, and .lnk files:

```
DIR "%userprofile%\Desktop" /b /s /a:-h-s | FIND /v "*.lnk">>"C:\some\file.txt"
```

the /b switch will return only the filename.ext, the /s switch returns all files in said directory AND subdirectories, and the /a:-hs switch removes all hidden and system files. Then of course FIND /v means to find all files NOT containing the following string.

Comment: Ah, this might very well prove very helpful. Will try it as soon as possible. Thanks a lot !